# Match until with priority

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following cases

```
F:xxxx xxxx#
F:xxxx xxxx
```

- if my string that comes after the F: ends with a hash ahead I want to match
  until the hash
- if my string doesn't have a hash ahead it will match until the first
  \b

so I came up with the following 2 expressions

```
F:(.+?)(?=#)
F:(.+?)(?=\b)
```

is it possible to combine both expressions and giving the hash a higher priority , what concept in regex should I be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[`if-else`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)** condition provided by regex like

```
^F:(?(?=.*#$).*$|\w*)
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
 F: #Match F: literally
  (? #Conditional regex begin
    (?=.*#$) #if-condition. # is in end of string
     .*$ #if above is true match entire string
     |
    \w* #else match word character. You can use .+?\b also
  )
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY6lW1/2)**

*.net code*

```
var pattern = "(?m)^F:(?(?=.*#$).*$|\\w*)";
var input = "F:xxxx xxxx#\nF:xxxx xxxx";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = rgx.Match(input);

while (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value.Trim());
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

**[.net fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GHR21B)**